# Mean Value Theorem: Continuous and Differential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Mean Value Theorem.  If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow R$ is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b), then there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ where

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} $$

I am having a hard time understanding why $f$ must be continuous on a closed interval and differential on open interval. What is the significance of having such a requirement? What if it was continuous on an open interval and differential on closed interval? Also why is it that there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ and not $c \in [a,b]$?

I don't know if a similar question has been asked before as I found no satisfactory post. If one has been asked previously, a link to the post would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go through the possible variations one by one

- **Continuous on the open internval, differentiable on the closed one**. Differentiable at $x$ implies continuous at $x$. Thus, the range of values where $f$ is continuous is always at least as large as the range of values where it is differentiable. So having $f$ continuous on the open interval but differentiable on the closed on doesn't make sense.
- **Continuous and Differentiable  on the open interval**. The theorem fails in this case. Let $f(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Since $f$ is *constant* on $(0,1)$, $f$ is clearly continuous and differentiable. But the derivative is identically zero, so $0 = f'(c) \neq \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0} = 1$ for all $c \in (0,1)$, contradicting the theorem.
- **Continuous on the closed interval, differentiable on less than the open interval**.
  The theorem fails in this case too. Let $f(x) = x$ if $x < \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$. $f'$ exists on $(0,1)\setminus\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}$, and takes only the values $2$ (on $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$) and $0$ (on $\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$). Yet again $\frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0} = 1$, so $\frac{f(1) - f(0)}{1-0} \neq f(c)$ for all $c$ where $f'$ exists.
- **Continuous and Differentiable on the closed interval**. This is strictly *weaker* than the original theorem, and therefore is of course true. But since the theorem *also* holds if we require differentiability only on the open interval, why state the weakened form, if we might just as well state the stronger one? The function $f(x) = (x-x^2)\sin \frac{1}{x-x^2}$ for $x=[0,1]$, where $f(0)=f(1)=0$ wittnesses that this version is actually *strictly* weaker. The function itself is continuous on $[0,1]$, since the factor $(x^2-x)$ ensures that it goes to zero as $x$ approaches $0$ respectively $1$. But the same *isn't* true for the derivative, and therefore the derivative exists only on $(0,1)$.

Thus the theorem is stated so that it is as general as possible while still being true.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, we need $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$ (closed), since if not we can have scenarios where $f(a),f(b)$, "blow up", violating the differentiability around these points, and making our quotient $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, plausibly not well defined.

And we need $f$ to be differentiable on $(a,b)$ (open) since, differentiation is not well defined on a closed interval, because we need to know what is happening at each side of a point, i.e. if we say $f$ is differentiable at some point $z$, then we have to know how the function behaves on the "left" and "right" of $z$.

This cannot happen on a closed interval, i.e $[a,b]$, since we do not know how the function is behaving on the "left" of $a$ or the "right" of $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the mean value theorem uses Rolle's theorem. In order to apply Rolle's theorem, $f$ has to be continuous on $[a,b]$, since the proof of Rolle's theorem uses the fact that a continuous function on a compact interval attains it's maximum. This is obviously false for non-compact intervals.

Comment: Well, of course $f$ has to be continuous on $[a,b]$ because that is what the theorem tells us. But my question is simple. Why?

Comment: @EamesCobb See my edit

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f'(c)$ is the slope of the  tangent line of the curve at the point $(c,f(c))$ so the geometric interpretation of the mean value theorem: there's $c$ in which the tangent line of the curve is parallel to the segment joining the point $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

[image]

If $f$ is not continuous on $[a,b]$ then we can find easily a counterexample as shown in the figure below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is differentiable le on the closed interval then it is also continuous on the closed interval. However, $f$ can be continuous on the closed interval, differentiable on the open interval and not differentiable on the closed interval.